# Difficult SQL join across tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that join easily and a third that is giving me trouble.  First, the tables:

```
tbl_customer
id  dt           value  group
a   2013-01-01   10     cavalry
a   2012-06-01   20     lance
a   2011-03-01   10     infantry
b   2013-01-01   20     court
b   2012-07-01   5      maiden
b   2005-06-01   10     chivalry

tbl_title
id  dt_active    dt_inactive   title
a   2001-01-01   2012-01-01    mister
a   2012-01-02   3001-01-01    sir
a   2012-01-02   3001-01-01    king
b   2001-01-01   2012-01-01    miss
b   2012-01-02   3001-01-01    lady
b   2012-01-02   3001-01-01    queen
```

This is easy to join to return a title for a given ID using:

```
SELECT 
  id, dt, value, title
FROM
  tbl_customer AS cust
INNER JOIN tbl_title AS titles
  ON titles.id = cust.id
  AND dt >= titles.dt_active
  AND dt <= titles.dt_inactive
```

This returns all of the rows in `tbl_customer` with some duplicates where there are multiple "active" titles.  For example, the first row in `tbl_customer` returns twice, once with "king" and once with "sir" as a `title`.

I have a third table that links groups to titles.  It can help resolve these relationships:

```
tbl_group
group     title   rank
cavalry   sir     10
lance     king    20
infantry  mister  30
court     lady    10
court     queen   20
maiden    lady    10
chivalry  miss    5
```

I can then join the tables to include the title from `tbl_group` and limit the results to those that match:

```
SELECT 
  id, dt, value, titles.title
FROM
  tbl_customer AS cust
INNER JOIN tbl_title AS titles
  ON titles.id = cust.id
  AND dt >= titles.dt_active
  AND dt <= titles.dt_inactive
INNER JOIN tbl_group AS group
  ON group.group = cust.group
WHERE
  titles.title = group.title
```

This largely solves my problems.  The third table helps to remove the ambiguity when there are multiple "active" records in `tbl_title`.

However, there is a problem.  The third table can also have multiple titles associated with a group.  Therefore, there can still be duplication in the final output.  In the example above, "cavalry" is unambiguously associated with the title "sir".  However,  the group "court" can be either "lady" or "queen", and `tbl_title` isn't any help either, since both "lady" and "queen" are active for the date in `tbl_customer`.

At this point, I have no other way to choose other than "rank" in `tbl_group`.  "Queen" outranks "lady" 20 to 10, so I want to use that title for the entry in `tbl_customer`.  If the ranks are equal, I want to just use the first record in `tbl_group`.  (*Could this be resolved with some kind of internal ordering?*)

The tricky part is that the active/inactive dynamic needs to be taken into account before the rank.  For example, I don't want to first filter `tbl_group` for one title per group, since that would prevent possible matches based on date.

Ideally, I need to return one row per entry from `tbl_customer` that shows title, first based on active/inactive date.  Next, I want to eliminate duplicates using `tbl_group`.  Finally, I want to limit the results to just one row per entry in `tbl_customer` using matching and rank from `tbl_group`.  Is this even possible?

Comment: Unrelated, but there's a `between` in SQL Server so you can use that to filter where a value is between the start date and end date, inclusive, in a one-liner instead of a `<=` and `>=`.

Comment: So I kind of skimmed your question a bit. You have 2 entities `customer` and `title`. First of all don't use the same keys - choose a new key system for `titles`. Then find an article on Google on `many to many relationships` and recreate your third table to describe this relationship between title and customer. If the model is right the rest of it will be far easier.

Comment: Hey, I definitely agree with you @bhs but I can't - it's stored this way in the data warehouse, and there's nothing I can do.  I would absolutely have designed it differently if I could.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I'll incorporate that!

Comment: Yeah sorry man - the real shame is that to make something work that's badly designed you have to feel the pain. There seem to be some good answers here though so good luck :-)

Comment: Thanks!  These were some great answers and solved the problem.  What a huge help!

Comment: @JeffreyKramer just a side note while using betwwen One thing to be careful of, is if you are using this against a DATETIME, the match for the end date will be the beginning of the day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, some actual table schema would be helpful as the table data you have provided is missing some key elements. What are the keys in each of the tables? I.e., what can be used to uniquely identify a row in each of the tables? What does the `id` column in the customer and title table represent? Surely not a customer identifier since there are duplicates.

Second, to answer your question, you can use a ranking function such as `Row_Number` to rank the items in your list and only return the first item for a given set:

```
With RnkItems As
  (
  Select C.id, C.dt, C.value, T.Title
    , Row_Number() Over ( Partition By C.id, C.dt, C.value, C.[group]
                          Order By G.rank Desc ) As Rnk
  From tbl_customer As C
    Join tbl_title As T
      On T.id = C.id
        And C.dt Between T.dt_active And T.dt_inactive
    Join tbl_group As G
      On G.[group] = C.[group]
        And G.title = T.title
  )
Select id, dt, value, title
From RnkItems
Where Rnk = 1
```

The key is the `Partition By C.id, C.dt, C.value, C.[group]` statement. Why all four columns? The reason is that I have no idea what uniquely identifies a customer row. If there were a primary key on that table, we could simply partition by that.

[SQL Fiddle version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a38f5/4)

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I was able to use the index cluster and it returned exactly what I needed.  Also, SQL Fiddle is almost as helpful as debbugex for me lately!  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT 
  id, 
  dt, 
  value, 
  titles.title, 
  group.rank MAX(rank) OVER(PARTITION BY cust.id) AS MAX_RANK
FROM
  tbl_customer AS cust
INNER JOIN tbl_title AS titles
  ON titles.id = cust.id
  AND dt BETWEEN titles.dt_active AND titles.dt_inactive
INNER JOIN tbl_group AS group
  ON group.group = cust.group
WHERE
  titles.title = group.title
) AS RESULTS
WHERE rank = MAX_RANK
```

The windowing function `MAX(rank) OVER(PARTITION BY cust.id)` will get the max rank per id.  Then we filter the rows to only return the row whose rank is that customer's maximum rank.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try and see if I can make it work.  I haven't used PARTITION BY often so this is good to learn.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY g.group, g.title ORDER BY g.rank DESC) rn
        FROM    tbl_customer с
        JOIN    tbl_title t
        ON      t.id = c.id
                AND c.dt BETWEEN t.dt_active AND t.dt_inactive
        JOIN    tbl_group g
        ON      g.[group] = c.[group]
                AND g.title = c.title
        ) q
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work because of the problem I mentioned at the bottom.  It's only returning results where the max rank is present without first checking for the applicable values by date.  It's on the right track so I'll see if I can modify it to get what I need.